# Google play services must be inported as android lib project while apps seems to not reference it?

Tags: android

Google Play services docs states that:

a) "You must add Google Play services as an Android library project"

b) "Select Add External Jars: + /extras/android/compatibility/v4/android-support-v4.jar" to the java building path

I would have expected that Google told me to point to "Google play lib project" from my application in a form of dependency i.e. "at Projects tab, Required projects on the build path", but NO!

Instead, Google tells me to point to "android-support-v4.jar" in Libraries tab as external jar.

Though I'm sure missing something, In my opinion there should have been a dichotomy between both instructions? i.e.:

1) if I'm pointing to "android-support-v4.jar" and not referencing the "Google play lib project" from my app project, then why "Google play lib project" is needed and how is linked to my app project?

2) If I would point my app project through project dependency to "Google play lib project" (hypothetically) then why "android-support-v4.jar" would have been needed?

Thank you very much for your support.

Jorge

Comment: I have never seen your "b)" step in the documentation, and it certainly does not sound correct.

Comment: The support library and Google Play Services are two different things but they are not mutually exclusive so this is not a dichotomy. (i.e. you cannot use Google Play Services on older flavour of Android without the support library).

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed google play services ,you should find this "android-support-v4.jar" inside your lib,but if not you can download it and create new project and copy it to this project inside lib/ folder.